# What does 0 0 1 mean in coordinate systems for 3d object?

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, three.js

I was reading and learning about coordinate systems in 3d and found that some people are using different explanations about rotation of coordinate system. 
What does it mean for 3d object to be drawn in coordinate system:

```
0 0 1
1 0 0
0 1 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is too general and I cannot be sure about the meaning of the matrix in every context. However, mathematically, when you represent a *coordinate system* with a matrix, the matrix is the one you use to change a vector from that coordinate system to the so called *canonical* system where a vector (x,y,z) corresponds to the *basis* E = {(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)}.

In your case if you have a vector `v` whose coordinates in this other system are `(a, b, c)`, you can compute the coordinates of `v` in the canonical basis multiplying the matrix by the column vector `(a, b, c)`:

```
| 0 0 1 | |a|   |c|
| 1 0 0 | |b| = |a|
| 0 1 0 | |c|   |b|
```

For example the vector whose coordinates are `(1, 2, 3)` in this system consist of the usual vector `(3, 1, 2)`.

You can use subindexes to annotate the coordinate system you are using. In your example if we set `B = {(0,1,0), (0,0,1), (1,0,0)}` (the columns of the matrix) we have:

(1, 2, 3)<sub>B</sub> = (3, 1, 2)<sub>E</sub> = (3, 1, 2) "with no E for the sake of simplicity"

Note that you can perform all kinds of linear operations with vectors in this basis and then transform the results to the canonical basis, or transform first to the canonical and operate after that. In both cases you will get the very same results. For instance,

1. (1, 2, 3)<sub>B</sub> + 4*(5, 6, 7)<sub>B</sub> = (21, 26, 31)<sub>B</sub> = (31, 21, 26)
2. (3, 1, 2) + 4*(7, 5, 6) = (31, 21, 26)

In 1 we operate in B and then transform. In 2 we transform and then operate. Both results are the same.

In sum,

1. The matrix M that represents a coordinate system of **R**<sup>3</sup> has in its columns the vectors of the basis B of such a system written in the (usual) canonic basis.
2. To calculate the canonic coordinates of a vector v written in B, multiply the matrix M by the column vector given by the coordinates of v in B: M[v]<sub>B</sub> = [v]<sub>E</sub>.
3. Because of 2 above, M can be regarded as the matrix that changes from B to E.
4. The matrix that changes (back) from E to B is the inverse M<sup>-1</sup>.